# Left outer join "The correlation name 'MMP_PPRVU' has the same exposed name as table 'MMP_PPRVU'."

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've been struggling with this for some time now. It's something to do with how I'm joining the MMP_PPRVU I believe. Essentially, I'm trying to join CLARITY_TDL_TRAN --> CLARITY_EAP1 --> MMP_PPRVU. As well as CLARITY_TDL_TRAN --> MMP_STAGING_UNITS --> MMP_PPRVU.

All left outer joins. I've tried multiple different approaches but cannot come up with a solution that works. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT........
FROM  

CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_TDL_TRAN as CLARITY_TDL_TRAN  
left outer join 
dbo.MMP_STAGING_UNITS as MMP_STAGING_UNITS on MMP_Staging_Units.eTDL_ID = CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.TDL_ID and CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.DETAIL_TYPE in (1, 10)
left outer join
CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_EAP as CLARITY_EAP on CLARITY_EAP.PROC_ID = CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.PROC_ID
left outer join
CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_EAP AS CLARITY_EAP1 on CLARITY_EAP1.PROC_ID = CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.PROC_ID --look into this alias
left outer join 
CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_POS as CLARITY_POS on CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.POS_ID = CLARITY_POS.POS_ID
left outer join
CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_DEP as CLARITY_DEP on CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.DEPT_ID = CLARITY_DEP.DEPARTMENT_ID
left outer join
CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_LOC as CLARITY_LOC on CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.LOC_ID = CLARITY_LOC.LOC_ID
left outer join
dbo.mmp_PatientsTestaYes as mmp_PatientsTestaYes on CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.INT_PAT_ID = mmp_PatientsTestaYes.PAT_ID
left outer join
CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_SA as CLARITY_SA on CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.SERV_AREA_ID = CLARITY_SA.SERV_AREA_ID
left outer join
CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_SER as CLARITY_SER on CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.PERFORMING_PROV_ID = CLARITY_SER.PROV_ID
left outer join
CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_EAF_TIN as CLARITY_EAF_TIN ON CLARITY_LOC.LOC_ID = CLARITY_EAF_TIN.FACILITY_ID
left outer join 
dbo.MMP_PPRVU as MMP_PPRVU on MMP_Staging_Units.eFinMod = MMP_PPRVU.MOD
left outer join 
dbo.MMP_revctrs$ as MMP_revctrs$ ON CLARITY_EAP.PROC_CODE = MMP_revctrs$.CPT
left outer join
MMP_PPRVU ON CLARITY_EAP_1.PROC_CODE = MMP_PPRVU.HCPCS
  WHERE        (CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.DETAIL_TYPE IN (1, 10)) AND       (mmp_PatientsTestaYes.PAT_ID IS NULL) AND (CLARITY_EAF_TIN.LINE = 1)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem you're encountering? The only thing I see so far is a misspelled alias reference.

Comment: Good call, I did not notice that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use indentation to help keep joins understandable.

You can see below that you give the second join against CLARITY_EAP the alias of CLARITY_EAP1 but then when you try to join against it you use the alias CLARITY_EAP_1 which isn't defined and is likely throwing an error.

```
SELECT........
FROM CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_TDL_TRAN as CLARITY_TDL_TRAN  
    left outer join dbo.MMP_STAGING_UNITS as MMP_STAGING_UNITS on MMP_Staging_Units.eTDL_ID = CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.TDL_ID and CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.DETAIL_TYPE in (1, 10)
        left outer join dbo.MMP_PPRVU as MMP_PPRVU1 on MMP_Staging_Units.eFinMod = MMP_PPRVU.MOD
    left outer join CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_EAP as CLARITY_EAP on CLARITY_EAP.PROC_ID = CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.PROC_ID
        left outer join dbo.MMP_revctrs$ as MMP_revctrs$ ON CLARITY_EAP.PROC_CODE = MMP_revctrs$.CPT
    left outer join CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_EAP AS CLARITY_EAP1 on CLARITY_EAP1.PROC_ID = CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.PROC_ID --look into this alias
        left outer join MMP_PPRVU as MMP_PPRVU2 ON CLARITY_EAP1.PROC_CODE = MMP_PPRVU2.HCPCS
    left outer join CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_POS as CLARITY_POS on CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.POS_ID = CLARITY_POS.POS_ID
    left outer join CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_DEP as CLARITY_DEP on CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.DEPT_ID = CLARITY_DEP.DEPARTMENT_ID
    left outer join CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_LOC as CLARITY_LOC on CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.LOC_ID = CLARITY_LOC.LOC_ID
        left outer join CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_EAF_TIN as CLARITY_EAF_TIN ON CLARITY_LOC.LOC_ID = CLARITY_EAF_TIN.FACILITY_ID
    left outer join dbo.mmp_PatientsTestaYes as mmp_PatientsTestaYes on CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.INT_PAT_ID = mmp_PatientsTestaYes.PAT_ID
    left outer join CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_SA as CLARITY_SA on CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.SERV_AREA_ID = CLARITY_SA.SERV_AREA_ID
    left outer join CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_SER as CLARITY_SER on CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.PERFORMING_PROV_ID = CLARITY_SER.PROV_ID
WHERE
    CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.DETAIL_TYPE IN (1, 10) AND
    mmp_PatientsTestaYes.PAT_ID IS NULL AND
    CLARITY_EAF_TIN.LINE = 1
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error with this but it's helping to clarify.

Comment: Msg 1012, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The correlation name 'MMP_PPRVU' has the same exposed name as table 'MMP_PPRVU'.

Comment: Look at the first join to MMP_PPRVU. You try to give it an alias, but the alias name is the same as the table name so when you reference that table again without an alias you're still creating an ambiguous reference. Make that alias MMP_PPRVU1 and in the second join to that table give it an alias MMP_PPRVU2. You don't strictly have to give both an alias, but can help to keep things explicit.

Comment: Also, if you're using a graphical query builder...don't. Do yourself a favor and take the time to learn to write SQL by hand. You'll develop a style that works well for you and save yourself a lot of headaches.

Comment: +100 on that. Someone else used a graphical query builder and I'm trying to make sense of it, originally it had many right outer joins and wierd stuff going on. I appreciate your help. I will play with this until I get it. What you all are saying is making sense and is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When you give a table an alias in your FROM clause, it's superflous to name the alias the same as the table name.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MMP_PPRVU AS MMP_PPRVU
    ON MMP_Staging_Units.eFinMod = MMP_PPRVU.MOD
```

Furthermore, you join in the same table a few JOIN's down and it's name is the same. One of these two tables will need to have an alias that is different from the table name. Perhaps:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MMP_PPRVU as MMP_PPRVU_1
    ON MMP_Staging_Units.eFinMod = MMP_PPRVU.MOD
```

So it doesn't conflict with:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN MMP_PPRVU
     ON CLARITY_EAP_1.PROC_CODE = MMP_PPRVU.HCPCS
```

I find it helpful to use slightly different indentation when writing my FROM clause so that these things stand out a bit more and it's easier to parse.

```
FROM CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_TDL_TRAN AS CLARITY_TDL_TRAN
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MMP_STAGING_UNITS AS MMP_STAGING_UNITS
        ON MMP_Staging_Units.eTDL_ID = CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.TDL_ID
            AND CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.DETAIL_TYPE IN (
                1,
                10
                )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_EAP AS CLARITY_EAP
        ON CLARITY_EAP.PROC_ID = CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.PROC_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_EAP AS CLARITY_EAP1
        ON CLARITY_EAP1.PROC_ID = CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.PROC_ID --look into this alias
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_POS AS CLARITY_POS
        ON CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.POS_ID = CLARITY_POS.POS_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_DEP AS CLARITY_DEP
        ON CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.DEPT_ID = CLARITY_DEP.DEPARTMENT_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_LOC AS CLARITY_LOC
        ON CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.LOC_ID = CLARITY_LOC.LOC_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.mmp_PatientsTestaYes AS mmp_PatientsTestaYes
        ON CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.INT_PAT_ID = mmp_PatientsTestaYes.PAT_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_SA AS CLARITY_SA
        ON CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.SERV_AREA_ID = CLARITY_SA.SERV_AREA_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_SER AS CLARITY_SER
        ON CLARITY_TDL_TRAN.PERFORMING_PROV_ID = CLARITY_SER.PROV_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_EAF_TIN AS CLARITY_EAF_TIN
        ON CLARITY_LOC.LOC_ID = CLARITY_EAF_TIN.FACILITY_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MMP_PPRVU AS MMP_PPRVU_1
        ON MMP_Staging_Units.eFinMod = MMP_PPRVU.MOD
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MMP_revctrs$ AS MMP_revctrs$
        ON CLARITY_EAP.PROC_CODE = MMP_revctrs$.CPT
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MMP_PPRVU
        ON CLARITY_EAP_1.PROC_CODE = MMP_PPRVU.HCPCS
```

Comment: I like this structure much better adding the criteria up front. Will this improve querying time?

Comment: Note: Adding the DETAIL_TYPE filter on the left-join conditions has a different effect from adding it in the where clause. In the where clause, it has the same effect as making the left join an inner join because it excludes nulls.

Comment: Oddly, it's in both the FROM clause and WHERE clause in the question itself. It's hard to see when the code is blobbed together.

Comment: @gfuller40, think of it this way: Applying a filter in the WHERE clause causes the filter to applied AFTER the Joins are made. Removing records where the filter is applied. Adding filters on a LEFT JOIN only cause records in the table being joined to not come into the results. Applying filters like this in an INNER JOIN will cause records from both the existing joined results and the table being joined to be dropped. You have to think through how the filter will be applied to the recordset at that point in the query's execution to know if this is a better choice for your query.